# Adding child node to treeview

Tags: c#, treeview

```
ProjectNumbers = DatabaseHandler.Instance.QuerySingleColumn(SelectProjectNumberQuery, "ProjectNumber");
      foreach (string ProjectNumber in ProjectNumbers)
      {
             ProjectTree.Nodes.Add(ProjectNumber);
             ProjectTree.EndUpdate();
             SelectWorkOrderNumberQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT WorkOrderNumber FROM dbo.SUBPRODUCTS WHERE ProjectNumber =" + Int32.Parse(ProjectNumber) + ";";
             WorkOrderNumbers = DatabaseHandler.Instance.QuerySingleColumn(SelectWorkOrderNumberQuery, "WorkOrderNumber");
                  foreach(string WorkOrderNumber in WorkOrderNumbers)
                  {                 
                      ProjectTree.Nodes[ProjectNumber].Nodes.Add(WorkOrderNumber); 
                  }
      }
```

I'm trying to fill my ProjectTree with ProjectNumbers and WorkOrderNumbers from an SQL database. The `ProjectTree.Nodes.Add(ProjectNumber)` is working fine within the first foreach loop.

When adding my WorkOrderNumber as a child (second foreach loop), I'm getting the object with no reference error, cant quite figure out why. Found some related topics where they use the `SelectedNode()` function, but that doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why are you calling `.ToString()` on a `string`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: @codran Corrected that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets try this :

```
 ProjectNumbers = DatabaseHandler.Instance.QuerySingleColumn(SelectProjectNumberQuery, "ProjectNumber");
          foreach (string ProjectNumber in ProjectNumbers)
          {
                                 var node = new TreeNode(ProjectNumber);

                 SelectWorkOrderNumberQuery = "SELECT DISTINCT WorkOrderNumber FROM dbo.SUBPRODUCTS WHERE ProjectNumber =" + Int32.Parse(ProjectNumber) + ";";
                 WorkOrderNumbers = DatabaseHandler.Instance.QuerySingleColumn(SelectWorkOrderNumberQuery, "WorkOrderNumber");
                      foreach(string WorkOrderNumber in WorkOrderNumbers)
                      {                 
                            var workNode = new TreeNode(WorkOrderNumber);
                    node.Nodes.Add(workNode);
                      }
 ProjectTree.Nodes.Add(node);
          }
```

Comment: Do you know *why* retaining a reference to the node works, but looking it up again fails?

Comment: because ProjectTree.Nodes[ProjectNumber] looking for a key, but when you add a node you just set a title for it